# Install MongoDB on Ambari Hadoop: Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: datastax

Tags: mongodb, hadoop, ambari

I am following the install instructions located at: https://github.com/nikunjness/mongo-ambari

However, Mongodb install step falls within ambari, the error outputs as:

`Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: datastax`

How can I successfully install?

Answer (score 0):

The error indicate, you have some repo file under /etc/yum.repos.d/ with repository name [datastax] but no baseurl mentioned. Though this repo file may not be necessary (if it does not contain repository details required for mongodb), hence you may either correct it or move it somewhere else.

And make sure you have repository details required for mongodb. 
Example.

```
[mongodb-org-3.4]
name=MongoDB Repository
baseurl=https://repo.mongodb.org/yum/redhat/$releasever/mongodb-org/3.4/x86_64/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
gpgkey=https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-3.4.asc
```

Comment: What is the file path to locate this?

Comment: The yum repo files will be in /etc/yum.repos.d/  directory.